# What is the symbolism of the tree canopy shots in It Follows?

Tags: analysis, it-follows

In the horror film It Follows, the protagonist has a number of introspective moments when she is seen looking at the tree canopy.

The director holds long shots for these scenes on the trees.  Does anyone know what the director is trying to say with these tree shots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several shots in the movie showing a 360 degrees panorama of the environment around a fixed location. 
It feels like the point of view of some of the characters, that would scan their surroundings for potential dangers. 
We viewers are very attentive during those shots; it is like if we shared the same burden as the characters, we are looking out for danger.

During the shots of the tree canopies, I would say that we can feel like the character, exhausted of continuously having to worry and check the surroundings, wishing we could just take a short break (by looking at the sky), but still very conscious that it might be fatal. 
I think it contributes to the atmosphere of the movie, that is both oppressive and grim.